# How to change vCenter server appliance IP from command line?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have installed a vCenter 5.1 appliance (VCSA) on physical server on a particular network, and assigned it an internal IP.  This server (Dell R620) then went to a remote hosting location, where it is connected to a network with has a totally different IP and subnet.

So what I need to do now is change the vCenter server's IP to one I can remotely connect to.

I can only Launch the Console of the appliance from within the Host machine itself.

[image]

How do I change the appliance IP using command line (logged in as root)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a comfortable way of doing this here:

[Allocate a static IP address to the VMware vCenter Server Appliance (VCSA) | Ivo Beerens' Blog](http://www.ivobeerens.nl/2013/01/14/allocate-a-static-ip-address-to-the-vmware-vcenter-server-appliance-vcsa/)

It also allows you to change hostname, DNS, default gateway and proxy.

To sum it up:

- Open a console session of the VCSA
- Login as: root
- Default password is: vmware
- Execute the following command: `/opt/vmware/share/vami/vami_config_net`
- After executing the command, a
  menu is displayed. Within the menu It is possible to change the IP
  address, hostname, DNS, Default gateway and proxy server.

After allocating a static IP Address to the VCSA, the post configuration can be done by using the following URL:

```
https://static-ip-address:5480
```

Comment: I just had to do this twice this week. This is correct.

Comment: To get this to work I had go into the  `http://<ip-address>:5480` interface and select Administration → Certificate Regeneration Enabled. I found that setting on this [VMware KB page](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=2058430). Rebooting several times may also have helped.

Comment: @andrew.n I confirm multiple reboot maked it work after the ip was changed, 3 reboot to be exact in my case ...

Answer (score 4):

I can't recall which specific Linix distro the VCA is built on but I think it's a RHEL variant, so just edit `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0` as root, it's all very obvious from there. Then just reboot or restart the networking service for the changes to come in.

Comment: great, the file is /etc/sysconfig/networking/devices   - what I do with the 'BROADCASTING' address?  what is that?  Gateway?

Comment: The broadcasting address is the broadcast address of your network. You can use http://www.subnet-calculator.com/ to calculate it, if you don't know what it is.

Comment: Didn't work until I symlinked to /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth1 as per http://vninja.net/virtualization/adding-secondary-nic-vcenter-5-1-appliance-vcsa/

Comment: Do NOT merely edit this file when changing the IP! You will receive errors with the Inventory and STS (secure token service, part of the SSO suite). These components must re-register under the new URL. The much better way is the way the vendor supports, in Jonas' answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of changing vCenter IP is indeed running:
/opt/vmware/share/vami/vami_config_net
from the console of the vCenter.
Another way is from the VAMI itself (https://vcenter:5480) if you have access.
Make sure to perform certificate regeneration after the IP change. One of the SANs (subject alternative names) of the certificate is the IP itself, hence you have to regenerate it even if the name does not change.

Login to VAMI , go to "admin" and tick "certificate regeneration enabled" to "yes".
Reboot and give it some time to finish the certificate regeneration. Could take 15-20 mins. You can track the progress in the console.
Once the process of certificate regeneration is finished and the console gets to the login screen, login to the VAMI again, go to "admin" and set "certificate regeneration enabled" to "no".

Alternative certificate regeneration method is described in
[Regenerating Self-Signed SSL Certificates in VMware vCenter Server appliance 5.1 or 5.5 (2070603) | VMware Knowledge Base](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2070603)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this from the GUI on the actual appliance. You use your browser to log into the appliance, then go to the "network" section and you can set it all there.

[image]

Comment: A nice command line interface. Glad to see you've read the question carefully.

Comment: I was offering this as an alternate, in case other users had similar but not identical questions. You can tell that because I started by "you can also..."  I'll have to keep in mind that this site is perhaps much more rigid, and not add anything beyond the very specific question.